# Using image_tag with srcset attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, srcset

I try to use an `srcset` attribute inside an `image_tag` but I can not make it work.

Im not sure if it is a syntax error or it generally does not work in an image_tag.

Is it possible to use a srcset attribute in an image_tag?

If yes, how?, and if not why not and is there a workaround?

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("logo.png", alt: "logo", :id => "logo"), root_path) %>
```

Comment: This has now been added to Rails 5.2.1 asset tag helper, see commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/43efae22a7a59d5fe0be599bd074c5e7d881266a#diff-d36c3bf0d0a61b0b5dbae953a4852ad2

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of adding the `image_tag` to the `link_to` "name" option you can use open up block and pass your image there.

If you want to use a `srcset` attribute you could *extend* the functionality of `image_tag` by creating a helper:

```
def image_set_tag(source, srcset = {}, options = {})
  srcset = srcset.map { |src, size| "#{path_to_image(src)} #{size}" }.join(', ')
  image_tag(source, options.merge(srcset: srcset))
end
```

It joins each size by comma, so then you can do:

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  <%= image_set_tag 'logo.jpg', { 
     'logo_640.jpg'  => '640w', 
     'logo_1024.jpg' => '1024w', 
     'logo_1980.jpg' => '1980w' 
   }, sizes: '100vw', alt: 'logo', id: 'logo' %>
<% end %>
```

---

As you can see, the changes introduced in `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper#image_tag` in the 5.2.1 Rails version allows you to pass the `srcset` option, with a hash or an array of 2D arrays containing the different responsive versions of your image:

```
image_tag("icon.png", srcset: { "icon_2x.png" => "2x", "icon_4x.png" => "4x" })
# => <img src="/assets/icon.png" srcset="/assets/icon_2x.png 2x, /assets/icon_4x.png 4x">

image_tag("pic.jpg", srcset: [["pic_1024.jpg", "1024w"], ["pic_1980.jpg", "1980w"]], sizes: "100vw")
# => <img src="/assets/pic.jpg" srcset="/assets/pic_1024.jpg 1024w, /assets/pic_1980.jpg 1980w" sizes="100vw">
```

So, if you're using a more recent Rails version, you can just use `image_tag` instead of writing your own implementation.